# Ant Build for Android proj:: how to create the myproject-release.apk (signed) to a folder other than bin?

Tags: android, ant, build, apk, release

Ant Build for Android proj:: how to create the myproject-release.apk (signed) to a folder other than bin?

I have over a 100 projects and do not want all the release apks to go to the same folder.
But i cannot seem to find a way to do this. anyone who knows how to get this done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom Ant task that [moves](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) the APK file after your production build. You would put that Ant task towards the bottom of `build.xml`, just inside the trailing `</project`> close tag. For example, here is a `jar` task that creates a JAR file:

```
  <target name="jar" depends="debug">
      <jar
          destfile="bin/CWAC-Layouts.jar"
          basedir="bin/classes"
      />
  </target>
```

In your case, you would create a task that uses `<move>`.

You will also want to modify the `<!-- version-tag: 1 -->` comment, just above where you are placing your Ant task, to be `<!-- version-tag: custom -->`. This will prevent Android's tools from clobbering your `build.xml` changes if they elect to modify `build.xml` themselves.

Then, run that Ant task.

Comment: thanks commonsware. But, I'm not very well versed with this. I'm still in the first hour of trying ant. Could you help me with steps? I'd really appreciate. where do i place the move task?